# How to change the layout of blog posts to that a compressed snippet shows rather than full text

Tags: blog, screen-layout

I'm new to Wordpress, started a blog, and can't figure out how to get the blog entries to display in a cutoff/compressed manner with the title and beginning text only. The default seems to be showing the full text, which means users can't easily get a sense of the kinds of posts. I'd like a setup like [this](https://gowers.wordpress.com/). I've been through the control panel and tried out options, but what am I missing? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Change `the_content()` with `the_excerpt()` in your template file\

Comment: @PieterGoosen thank you for this suggestion, but I don't see a template file available via the user interface.